# Appending to a vector in a for-loop of a specific value from a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, append, bioinformatics

I've recently ran into a problem with a pretty simple task. So, I have a data frame called `tissue.position` which contains an x-position (in the 5th column) and a y-position (in the 6th column). I only want to extract specific elements with specific index positions, and the indexes of the positions of elements that I need to extract are stored in a vector called `index_of_matched`. I would like to extract the elements with these specific indices and there corresponding x- and y-positions. I have the following code:

```
x_position <- c()
y_position <- c()

for (i in length(index_of_matched)) {
  a = index_of_matched[i]
  x_position <- append(x_position, as.vector(tissue.position[a,5]))
  y_position <- append(y_position, as.vector(tissue.position[a,6]))
}

spatial.data <- data.frame(x_position,y_position)
```

`spatial.data` is the name of the data frame where I store the specifically chosen x- and y-coordinates. However, when I run the code I somehow only get one single element for x- and y-coordinates respectively. When I check the number of indices that I want to extract it is about 3700, which means that something is wrong. The output seems to be a sum of the coordinates. Here is the output:

```
x-position  y-position
22117   19328
```

Where did I go wrong in my code? Thank you for any help in advance!

Comment: Hard to tell without a reproducible example, however, you can just do `spatial.data <- data.frame(tissue.position[index_of_matched, 5:6])` and then just rename the columns if you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing wrong is that `i in length(index_of_matched)` is just one number, not iterating through a range. A corrected version would be `i in seq_along(index_of_matched)`.

However, using `for` loops like this is non-idiomatic, since R has more expressive ways of accomplishing the same thing:

```r
x_position <- tissue.position[index_of_matched, 5]
y_position <- tissue.position[index_of_matched, 6]

spatial.data <- data.frame(x_position,y_position)
```

or, since `tissue.position` is already a `data.frame`, simply

```r
spatial.data <- tissue.position[index_of_matched, c(5,6)]
```

Comment: Of course....... I totally forgot that you could accomplish this without a for-loop. I'm quite new to R, and I'm more used to Python, so I was thinking in terms of Python. Thank you, thank you so much for the help!